# bash でフォアグラウンドで実行したジョブをバックグラウンドに移行させることはできますか？

Tags: bash

たとえば、 mysqldump を実行するとき、 `-p` オプションを指定すると、パスワードを標準入力からクエリするような動作になります。

この、最初の処理が始まる前のクエリはフォアグラウンドだが、その後の本処理がスタートした後はバックグラウンドで実行したいような場面は、いくつか他にもあると思っています。

#### 質問

- bash において、フォアグラウンドで実行したジョブを、途中からバックグラウンドに移行させることはできますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>で停止したジョブを`bg`コマンドでバックグラウンドにできます。

Comment: Ctrl-Z が諸事情により使えない人のための補足: フォアグラウンドで動いているプロセスに対して `kill -SIGTSTP プロセスID` によって、 `Ctrl-Z` と同じ効果を得ることができます。